# Complex taxonomy tree

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I am stuck in the following situation:

I have the following structure for Shoes Store:

- Men: which has under it specific categories;
- Women: has the same categories like Men
- Kids: has different categories.

I made a taxonomy tree as:
Vocabulary: **Shoes**

Shoes > Men > Categories

Shoes > Women > Categories

Shoes > Kids> Categories

But in this case I am stuck in filtering those taxonomy terms in my view. Any solution that suppose to work with this? or other taxonomy structure?

Best

Comment: Does this answer your question? drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36217/clean-way-of-building-simple-taxonomy-browser-of-arbitrary-depth I'm not really clear on what you're trying to build, exactly.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, I do not know if this run with me I will check. To clarify my problem: I have a content type called Shoes, through this content type I should be able to add products of type Men, Women, and Kids. I need a good and clean taxonomy hierarchy that enables me to add those types of products very easily. I have tried to build a taxonomy like Shoes>Men>Categories and so on for Women and Kids. But When I intend to view those products and filter them I have problems. What is the best sol? to separate content types?

Comment: or separate Vocabularies one for each main category (Men, Women, and Kids)? or just build a view for each one this will resulted in too many views. Sorry if I am not too obvious!

Comment: What I meant by "what are you trying to build" was, what frontend behavior are you wanting?